# Problem with runtime compilation in C#?

Tags: c#, runtime, compilation

I want to download the code from http://pastehtml.com/view/awono3xoq.txt, save it to a string, then compile & run it when the button is clicked, but I can't seem to get the code below to work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

namespace ASV
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void compile()
    {
        CSharpCodeProvider myCodeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        ICodeCompiler myCodeCompiler = myCodeProvider.CreateCompiler();
        String [] referenceAssemblies = {"System.dll"};
        string myAssemblyName = "Assembly.exe";
        CompilerParameters myCompilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(referenceAssemblies, myAssemblyName);
        myCompilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        myCompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        WebClient x = new WebClient();
        Stream y = x.OpenRead("http://pastehtml.com/view/awono3xoq.txt");
        StreamReader z = new StreamReader(y);
        string source = z.ReadToEnd();
        z.Close();
        y.Close();
        CompilerResults compres = myCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(myCompilerParameters, source);
        Process.Start("Assembly.exe");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        compile();
    }
}
}
```

what am I doing wrong (other than having too many using statments :P)?

Comment: You need to say *what* doesn't work. Do you get an error? If so, what's the complete exception? If it doesn't do what you expect it to do, say how its behavior differs from what you expect.

Comment: Does it compile? Do you get any errors? Are exceptions thrown?

Comment: Using single letter variable names outside of a loop counter is a good way to get jumped in the parking lot after work.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, the error I get comes from running "Process.Start("Assembly.exe"); the error is the system can't find the file specified. this also happens when GenerateInMemory = false. I think that for somereason it doesn't compile it, but it still doesn't throw an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check  `CompilerResults compres` it shows that there's an exception and the compilation was not successful and hence it's not writing out `Assembly.exe` and there is a `System.IO.FileNotFound` exception from `Process.Start()`

Try this

```
public void compile()
{
    CSharpCodeProvider myCodeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    ICodeCompiler myCodeCompiler = myCodeProvider.CreateCompiler();
    string myAssemblyName = @"Assembly.exe";
    CompilerParameters myCompilerParameters = new CompilerParameters
                                                  {
                                                      OutputAssembly = myAssemblyName,
                                                      GenerateExecutable = true,
                                                      GenerateInMemory = true
                                                  };
    myCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
    WebClient x = new WebClient();
    Stream y = x.OpenRead("http://pastehtml.com/view/awono3xoq.txt");
    StreamReader z = new StreamReader(y);
    string source = z.ReadToEnd();
    z.Close();
    y.Close();
    CompilerResults compres = myCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(myCompilerParameters, source);
    Process.Start(myAssemblyName);
}
```

Comment: I found the problem :$ I put 

    Console.WriteLine(\"The Web Say OHAITHERE\");

thinking that it would recognize the " and terminate the string :( after removing the \s, the problem fixed itself.

Comment: @IMAPC it started working for me all of a sudden and it took a while for me to realize you had changed something in the source URL :). so always check for `compres.Errors.HasErrors` before trying to run the output.

Comment: umm, how do I get the errors out of CompilerResults after i know i have errors?

Comment: I would guess `foreach(var error in CompilerResults.Error){...}`